# solving long equation with matrix algebra

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to solve the long equation below using matrix algebra.  I have been able to do so.  However, my solution seems overly complex.  I had to break the equation into three parts delineated by the `#####` shown below:

Could someone suggest a more efficient solution?  Sorry if this question belongs on a different forum.  I suppose it could be viewed as either a programming issue or a matrix algebra issue.

Here is the equation:

```
a1 <- 0.1
a2 <- 0.2
a3 <- 0.3
a4 <- 0.4
b1 <- 1
b2 <- 2
b3 <- 3
b4 <- 4
b5 <- 5
b6 <- 6
b7 <- 7
b8 <- 8
c1 <- 10
c2 <- 20
c3 <- 30
c4 <- 40

x1 <- (a1 * b1 * c1  +
       a2 * b1 * c1  +
       a3 * b2 * c1  +
       a4 * b2 * c1  +
       a1 * b3 * c1  +
       a2 * b3 * c1  +
       a3 * b4 * c1  +
       a4 * b4 * c1  +
       a1 * b1 * c2  +
       a2 * b1 * c2  +
       a3 * b2 * c2  +
       a4 * b2 * c2  +
       a1 * b3 * c2  +
       a2 * b3 * c2  +
       a3 * b4 * c2  +
       a4 * b4 * c2  +
#####
       a1 * b5 * c3  +
       a2 * b5 * c3  +
       a1 * b6 * c3  +
       a2 * b6 * c3  +
       a1 * b5 * c4  +
       a2 * b5 * c4  +
       a1 * b6 * c4  +
       a2 * b6 * c4  +
#####
       a3 * b7 * c3  +
       a4 * b7 * c3  +
       a3 * b8 * c3  +
       a4 * b8 * c3  +
       a3 * b7 * c4  +
       a4 * b7 * c4  +
       a3 * b8 * c4  +
       a4 * b8 * c4  )
```

Here is my solution.

```
m.a1     <- matrix(c(a1, a2, a3, a4), nrow=1, ncol=4, byrow = TRUE) 
m.b1     <- matrix(c(b1,  b3,
                     b1,  b3,
                     b2,  b4,
                     b2,  b4), nrow=4, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
m.ab1    <- m.a1 %*% m.b1
m.c1     <- matrix(c(c1, c2,
                     c1, c2), nrow=2, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
m.abc1   <- m.ab1 %*% m.c1
#####
m.a2     <- matrix(c(a1, a2, a1, a2), nrow=1, ncol=4, byrow = TRUE) 
m.b2     <- matrix(c(b5,
                     b5,
                     b6,
                     b6), nrow=4, ncol=1, byrow=TRUE)
m.ab2    <- m.a2 %*% m.b2
m.c2     <- matrix(c(c3, c4), nrow=1, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
m.abc2   <- m.ab2 %*% m.c2
#####
m.a3     <- matrix(c(a3, a4, a3, a4), nrow=1, ncol=4, byrow = TRUE) 
m.b3     <- matrix(c(b7,
                     b7,
                     b8,
                     b8), nrow=4, ncol=1, byrow=TRUE)
m.ab3    <- m.a3 %*% m.b3
m.c3     <- matrix(c(c3, c4), nrow=1, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
m.abc3   <- m.ab3 %*% m.c3
#####
x2 <- sum(m.abc1) + sum(m.abc2) + sum(m.abc3)
x1 == x2
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Are you asking for a code review? Because there's a separate site for that [codereview.se]. Rather than just dumping code, it would be better to describe what you need to accomplish in words. There may already be functions that do exactly what you need (but it's hard to guess intent from code alone). At all the values `a1`, `a2`, ..., `c4` really separate variables in the real application? How do you read those into R? Hand type them?

Comment: Yes, I am hand typing the values in.  The general problem is similar to multiplying all possible combinations and adding the products.  However, I do not think that is a general enough approach.  I need to leave the computer for a couple of hours but can check back afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution that seems much more efficient.

```
a1 <- 0.1
a2 <- 0.2
a3 <- 0.3
a4 <- 0.4
b1 <- 1
b2 <- 2
b3 <- 3
b4 <- 4
b5 <- 5
b6 <- 6
b7 <- 7
b8 <- 8
c1 <- 10
c2 <- 20
c3 <- 30
c4 <- 40

x1 <- (a1 * b1 * c1  +
       a2 * b1 * c1  +
       a3 * b2 * c1  +
       a4 * b2 * c1  +
       a1 * b3 * c1  +
       a2 * b3 * c1  +
       a3 * b4 * c1  +
       a4 * b4 * c1  +

       a1 * b1 * c2  +
       a2 * b1 * c2  +
       a3 * b2 * c2  +
       a4 * b2 * c2  +
       a1 * b3 * c2  +
       a2 * b3 * c2  +
       a3 * b4 * c2  +
       a4 * b4 * c2  +

       a1 * b5 * c3  +
       a2 * b5 * c3  +
       a3 * b7 * c3  +
       a4 * b7 * c3  +
       a1 * b6 * c3  +
       a2 * b6 * c3  +
       a3 * b8 * c3  +
       a4 * b8 * c3  +

       a1 * b5 * c4  +
       a2 * b5 * c4  +
       a3 * b7 * c4  +
       a4 * b7 * c4  +
       a1 * b6 * c4  +
       a2 * b6 * c4  +
       a3 * b8 * c4  +
       a4 * b8 * c4  )

m.a     <- matrix(c(a1, a2, a3, a4), nrow=1, ncol=4, byrow = TRUE)

m.b     <- matrix(c(b1,  b3,  b5,  b6,
                    b1,  b3,  b5,  b6,
                    b2,  b4,  b7,  b8,
                    b2,  b4,  b7,  b8), nrow=4, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)

m.ab    <- m.a1 %*% m.b1

m.c     <- matrix(c(c1, c2,
                    c1, c2,
                    c3, c4,
                    c3, c4), nrow=4, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)

m.abc   <- m.ab %*% m.c
x3 <- sum(m.abc)

x3 == x1
#[1] TRUE
x3 == x2
#[1] TRUE
```